# What infill settings and material type do I need?

Tags: pla, abs

I’m trying to have [this bracket](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2576121) printed, but I don’t know what settings I should use.

[image: Google Home Mini Invisible Mount]

The project details say 50% for infill, but is there a reason why I wouldn’t get 100% for making it sturdier?  I imagine the developer used 50% because he used his own printer and wanted to preserve more material.  The 3D printer service I’m using doesn’t charge more for 100%.

But I’m more concerned about the material I should select.  Should I select PLA or ABS?  The developer didn’t specify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a small item and the small load it will carry, even 50 percent is substantial. Keep in mind that one hundred percent infill is not necessarily stronger. If you need to know why, consider a 'net search for "why not use 100% infill" for more detailed information. The primary foundation for not using 100% infill is that the stress is better distributed over the structure of a non-100% part, while the completely filled part has more intra-layer stress failure. Another link suggests that there's a possibility of increased warping with full infill.

Because the load is small, it matters very little if you select PLA over ABS. PLA is more brittle compared to ABS and will crack or fracture or break under loads that might otherwise cause the same part in ABS to bend.

If you need yet more strength, select PETG or nylon, although I suspect either one would be more expensive from a service.

If you select ABS, you can use acetone smoothing later to make a shiny surface, but that's cosmetic, not structural.

Comment: This is definitely a great answer.  The short of it is there's almost never a reason to print at 100% infill.

Comment: Also, If you need yet more strength, you might want to design a sturdier construction for starters. Where did it break, and why, are questions that'll help you move forwards in the search for stronger parts.

Answer (score 2):

You should use PLA at 215 °C (for better layer adhesion) with 35 percent infill and a shell thickness of 2 mm. Shell thickness is what's crucial here, not necessarily infill. The thicker the shell, the stronger the part. This has a much bigger influence on strength than infill does.

Comment: +1 for slightly bumped temperature. Do check you're not, even slightly, under extruding too as that can way reduce the sturdiness of a piece.